# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I get an error while using command parameter with type `sqldbtype.datatime`

Here is the code I'm using

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Posted_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"]);
```

Error is "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime" and value of dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"] is "2008-10-01 00:00:00.000" –

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: Waht is the value of dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"] when you receive the error?

Comment: getting this error "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime"  and value of dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"] is "2008-10-01 00:00:00.000"

Comment: @Naresh: Are you sure the value of the row is `2008-10...`. Did you debug and inspect the value when the application was run?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540932/how-to-pass-default-value-to-date-parametere-in-storedprocedure-sqlserver-2008



plz give me the reason why i get this type of error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the language of the login account in SQL Server does not match your ui culture language.

.NET is trying to convert the date you passed to a date format in sql server. It will transmit the date from the clinet as a string and it can't convert it because the client culture is different than the default "language" set for the SQL Server login.

To solve this you need to match the language for the sql server session with a `set language xxxxx` or change the language for the login with SQL Management Studio or change the SQL Server default language.

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
Convert.ToDateTime Method (String, IFormatProvider)
```

Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent date and time, using the specified culture-specific formatting information.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you need to parse the DateTime like:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"].ToString(),
                         "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Posted_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
```

Since your string contains the DateTime Format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`, you may use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with your date format.

Comment: @Naresh, at what line you get the error, I just tried it and it seems to be working fine

Comment: @Habib: Noticed you named the datetime variable the same as the datatable (or whatever the dt variable is). Hope you don't mind me changing it

Comment: In db parameter type is also datetime

Comment: @Naresh What did you do to make this work. I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

`(convert(varchar,messagePostedDate,101)) as messagePostedDate` use this in your select query
here is a link for refrence it has all casting and conversion of T-SQL
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: What's the point in converting it at the sql server when .net has great support for adding datetime parameters to a sqlcommand?

Comment: @Patrick its how i solved, just trying to help if it solves the problem.

Comment: u can use 121 instead of 101,

Comment: @Naresh remove the casting and see, it should work `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Posted_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"];`

Comment: it is because sqlparameter accept string as a value not datetime. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: have you used tostring() after this `dt.Rows[i]["messagePostedDate"]`

Comment: try with toString(), convert.toString() and without conversion but not working getting same error msg