# how to pass default value to date parametere in storedprocedure - Sqlserver 2008?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, default-value

Here it is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[allrecp]
    @peid int=0,
    @pename varchar(20)='',
    @pdes varchar(20)='',
    @pdoj date='1111-1-1',
    @sal money=0,
    @dept int=0,
    @loc int=0,@i int=0
    as begin
    if(@i=1)
    begin
    insert into Employee values(@pename,@pdes,@pdoj,@sal,@dept,@loc)
    end
    if(@i=2)
    begin
    update Employee set ENAME=@pename,DESEGNATION=@pdes,DOJ=@pdoj,SALARY=@sal,DEPTID=@dept,LOCATIONID=@loc WHERE EMPID=@peid
    end
    if(@i=3)
    delete EMPLOYEE where EMPID=@peid
end
```

And my c# code is:

```
private void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parameteres(3);
}

private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parameteres(2);
}

private void BTNINSERT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    parameteres(1);
}

public void parameteres(int i)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "allrecp";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@peid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = txtempid.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = txtename.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pdes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)).Value = txtdesg.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pdoj", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = txtdoj.Text;
```

Here i face the problem:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime

Code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dept", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = txtdept.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sal", SqlDbType.Money)).Value = txtsal.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loc", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = txtlocation.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@i", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = i;
con.Open();
int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show(x + " rows effected");
```

here i face the problem:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dept", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = txtdept.Text;
```

How to pass default values in to stored procedure?

Comment: Why you have defined     @pdoj date='1111-1-1',  . Try with     pdoj date='1111-01-01' . Also i would recomend to use datepicker instead of textbox

Comment: @askreva but the problem is occured in front end

Comment: are you sure the problem is in front end? I think its hitting your stored procedure and thats why returning you error.

Comment: may be sir...becoz we need to pass all values in compalsary ..other wise it gives error...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sachin's answer i would recomed you to use datepicker control or validate textbox to only accept date values using validators.

Comment: Iam not passes any value to txtdoj fromfront end it will taken as null values automatiacally

Comment: when i am create table doj data type is date

Comment: @mahesh you mean you will not pass any value from frontend to pdoj date?

Comment: Then you dont even need to have that parameter. Just set date to '1753-01-01' to your column

Comment: i will get same error sir.. mandatory should pass the all values it will not taken default values to backend..

Comment: Can we chat. Its difficult to understand your problem in this way.

Answer (score 0):

1- How to pass default date value:

A parameter ,with default value, inside SP makes it optional.
You may set a default inside SP, for a parameter and do not pass the parmeter at all when calling the SP from code, in that way it would consider your default value.

In your SP

```
@pdoj date='1111-1-1' -- Make sure to use a valid date. The min valid date for SQL server is `1753-1-1`
```

Is an optional parameter, when you do not have any value available at UI, then do not pass the parameter while calling SP, hence it would consider the default value.

2- Make sure, not to pass empty string/invalid date instead, just bypass the adding date parameter when no date is entered by user OR validate it as per your business rule

So, adding date parameter should be added conditionally, something like this:

```
if(  IsValidDate(txtdoj.Text) )
{
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pdoj", SqlDbType.Date)).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdoj.Text);
}
```

//*** IsValidDate is just a hint that you need to validate date as per business rule.. wither to consider empty date as invalid or allow default date to be considered.

Comment: it is my table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMPLOYEE](
 [EMPID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ENAME] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [DESEGNATION] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [DOJ] [date] NOT NULL,
 [SALARY] [money] NULL,
 [DEPTID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [LOCATIONID] [int] NOT NULL)

Comment: and my datatype in table is date..then how o use date time

Comment: Leave the SP and Table date for DOJ but change the data type to string in code:cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pdoj", SqlDbType.String)).Value = txtdoj.Text; // But make sure textbox contains a valid date.

Comment: here plz remember one thing i am not passed any values rather i give only one value to txtempid..only

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default parameter of date type as follows:

```
@Date Date = 'october 10, 2012'
```